# composer install, post-autoload-dump event returns with error

Tags: php, composer-php, installation, autoload, dump

Composer Install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   PHP artisan package: discover
>   Script PHP artisan package: discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with an error

```
[RuntimeException]
```

Error Output:

```
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--
no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--
optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of laravel/installer by running `composer global update`.

Comment: I am getting this error on my domain and I do not have access to the global composer update functionality.

Comment: But the above error is because your composer is not updated. You have to update it.